# Xamarin Android: getting color value from colors.xml programmatically

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

How can I get value of color programmatically from colors.xml file into C# code?

Here is my colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <item name="row_a" type="color">#FFCCFFCC</item>
  <item name="row_b" type="color">#FFFFFFCC</item>
  <item name="all_text" type="color">#FF000000</item>
  <item name="row_red" type="color">#FFFF4444</item>
  <item name="row_orange" type="color">#FFE69900</item>
  <item name="row_green" type="color">#FF739900</item>
  <item name="wheat" type="color">#FFF5DEB3</item>

  <integer-array name="androidcolors">
    <item>@color/row_a</item>
    <item>@color/row_b</item>
    <item>@color/all_text</item>
    <item>@color/row_red</item>
    <item>@color/row_orange</item>
    <item>@color/row_green</item>
    <item>@color/wheat</item>
  </integer-array>

</resources>
```

I tried:

```
Color t = (Color)Resource.Colors.wheat;
```

but of course I cannot convert int value to Color this way.

**EDIT:**

As suggested I tried

```
Color t = Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.row_a);
```

But it gives me an error:

```
Error   CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, 
method, or property 'Resources.GetColor(int)'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem was that I tried to access Resources from ListView Adapter. Solution is to use:

```
parent.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.row_a)
```

where `parent` is passed into `public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method.

Comment: This method is depricated now, now you can do it this way `new Android.Graphics.Color(ContextCompat.GetColor(this, Resource.Color.color_name))`

Comment: @CodeIt Out of curiosity, do you know *why* the `Resources.GetColor` method was deprecated?  This new `ContextCompat` way of doing things seems extremely verbose

Comment: EVERYTHING in Android is verbose. Look how much trouble it is to get a simple color when you want it. If we did our jobs the way they do theirs, we would be fired...

Answer (score 11):

Try this code:

```
  Color t = new Android.Graphics.Color (ContextCompat.GetColor (this, Resource.Color.row_a));
```

Comment: ContextCompat does not even contain GetColor method! any ideas?

Comment: Forget it. Updating the package Xamarin.Android.Support.V4 from NuGet fixed the issue. I was trying an old sample which contained an old version of the package so it was not showing up.

Comment: `Android.Support.V4.Content.ContextCompat.GetColor(this, Resource.Color.my_color)`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstancesState)
    {
        // check your Resources/Resource.designer.cs file
        int nResId = Resource.Color.row_a;
        var colorValue = ApplicationContext.GetColor(nResId);
    }
}
```

[Android.Content.Context.GetColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.content.context.getcolor?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12)

[Android Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/?tabs=windows)